# Friis transmission equation (log scale calculation)

Tags: antenna, transmitter, receiver, transmission

I am trying to understand the Friis transmission equation.
My scenario:  I consider transmit antennas (\$T_x\$) and receive antennas (\$R_x\$) at a distance R [km]. f [GHz], \$G_{T_x}\$ and \$G_{R_x}\$ in dBi, \$L_a\$ in dB ( loss) (<0).
\$G_{R_x}\$ =0 that is why I would like to make a calculation in logarithmical scale.
Friis equation:
\$P_r=P_tG_tG_r(\lambda/4\pi R)^2L_a\$

and then I wrote in log scale:

\$P_r(dB)=P_t(dB)+G_t(dB)+G_r(dB) + 10 log(\lambda/4\pi R)^2 + 10log(L_a)\$

In Fundamentals of Digital Communication by Upamanyu Madhow, p 134
[image]

1. Why is G in log scale in dBi ? I thought that dBi is in log scale dB
2. \$L_a\$ in dB, in log scale is it also in dB?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is G in log scale in dBi ? I thought that dBi is in log scale dB

In case you didn't know dBi means the gain of a real antenna compared to the gain of the theoretical but useful isotropic antenna. So when the formula says this: -

$$G_{RX,dBi}$$

It refers to the gain of the actual receive antenna compared to the gain of an isotropic antenna and expressed in decibels.

> La in dB, in log scale is it also in dB?

No, \$L_a\$ is a real number because it is converted to a decibel value by your main equation that you wrote.